# Consent form GDPR UserMessagingPlatform: No available form can be built

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, gdprconsentform

I am using Obtaining Consent with the User Messaging Platform in my application: https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start

The consent form is not shown on the screen at the start of the activity.

The logs show the triggering of the method after onResume, but the form does not appear on the eran. What's wrong with my code?

In run, I found the lines:

UserMessagingPlatform: No available form can be built.

D / UserMessagingPlatform: Stored info not exists: IDFA_freqCapNumViews
Stored info not exists: IABTCF_TCString
Stored info not exists: IABTCF_AddtlConsent
I / System.out: (HTTPLog) -Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
(HTTPLog) -Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

D / UserMessagingPlatform: Action [clear]: {"keys": ["IABTCF_CmpSdkID", "IABTCF_CmpSdkVersion", "IABTCF_PolicyVersion", "IABTCF_gdprApplies", "IABTCF_PublisherCC", "IABTCFreat_Streats" , "IABTCF_VendorLegitimateInterests", "IABTCF_PurposeConsents", "IABTCF_PurposeLegitimateInterests", "IABTCF_SpecialFeaturesOptIns", "IABTCF_PublisherConsent", "IABTCF_PublisherLegitimateInterests", "IABTCF_PublisherCustomPurposesConsents", "IABTCF_PublisherCustomPurposesLegitimateInterests", "IABTCF_AddtlConsent", "IABTCF_UserConsentRecordId", "IABTCF_idfaFlowControl"]}
D / UserMessagingPlatform: Action [write]: {"IABTCF_idfaFlowControl": 2}

What's wrong with my code?

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "ART_APP";
    private SharedPreferences sp;

    private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
    private ConsentForm consentForm;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.sp = getSharedPreferences(Sp.SP_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
                .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings
                        .DebugGeography
                        .DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
                .addTestDeviceHashedId("C258BF9BE13D842B973A20309A39C080")
                .build();

        ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
                .build();

        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                        if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                            loadForm();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.

                    }
                });
    }




    public SharedPreferences getSp() {
        return sp;
    }
    public void loadForm(){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "showconsent");
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        BaseActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if(consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    BaseActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });

                        }

                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        /// Handle Error.
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    /**
     * Достать строку из переменных
     *
     * @param stringId
     * @return
     */
    public String getSpString(String stringId) {
        return getResources().getString(sp.getInt(stringId, 0));
    }


    /**
     * @param stringId
     * @return
     */
    public String getSpStringSt(String stringId) {
        return sp.getString(stringId, "");
    }

    public void log(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }

    /**
     * Открываем ссылку в баузере
     *
     * @param url
     */
    public void showLink(String url) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
    }


    /**
     * Есть ли подписка ?
     *
     * @return
     */

}
```

```
public class CategoryActivity extends BaseActivity implements RVAdapter.ItemClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener, BarMenu.OnItemClick {

    private static final String TAG = CategoryActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private List<Item> items;
    private List<Modal> modals;
    private BarMenu barMenu;
    private HashMap<Integer, MoreApp> moreApps;

    private AdView adView;
    private FrameLayout adContainerView;

    private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
    private ConsentForm consentForm;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";




    private SliderView sliderView;
    private SliderPromoAdapter adapter;

    private ArrayList<SliderItem> sliderViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    private View banner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "CategoryCreate");
        initRateMe();
        showRateMe();
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) { }
        });


        //StartAppSDK.init(this, "202286925", true);
        //------------
        this.barMenu = new BarMenu(this, R.menu.top_bar_menu);
        barMenu.setOnItemClick(this);
        //------------
        adapter = new SliderPromoAdapter(this);

        SliderItem sliderItem = new SliderItem();
        sliderItem.setSource(R.drawable.banner_premium);
        sliderItem.setType(GlobalData.TYPE_PREMIUM);
        sliderViewArrayList.add(sliderItem);

        sliderView = findViewById(R.id.slider_view);
        sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.WORM); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.IndicatorAnimations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
        sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
        sliderView.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
        sliderView.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
        sliderView.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
        sliderView.setScrollTimeInSec(4); //set scroll delay in seconds :
        sliderView.startAutoCycle();
        sliderView.setSliderAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.renewItems(sliderViewArrayList);

        ///get the reference to your FrameLayout
        adContainerView = findViewById(R.id.adView_container);
        //Create an AdView and put it into your FrameLayout
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adContainerView.addView(adView);
        String adUnitId = getResources().getString(getSp().getInt(Sp.SP_ADS_BANNER_ID, 0));
        adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);

        //start requesting banner ads
        loadBanner();



        //------------
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_bar_title)).setText(
                getSp().getInt(Sp.SP_APP_NAME, 0)
        );
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        this.moreApps = new HashMap<>();

        /*
        if (!getSp().getBoolean(Sp.SP_MORE_APP_UP, false)) {
            readJson();
        }*/
        //TODO Есть ли вообще другие приложения ?)
        try {
            if (!getSpStringSt(Sp.SP_MORE_APPS).equals("")) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TypeToken<List<MoreApp>>() {
                }.getType();
                List<MoreApp> ma = gson.fromJson(getSpStringSt(Sp.SP_MORE_APPS), type);
                for (MoreApp m : ma) {
                    moreApps.put(m.getPosition(), m);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Баннер
        this.banner = findViewById(R.id.custom_banner);
        banner.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (getSp().getBoolean(Sp.SP_IS_FREE5DAY, false)) {
            banner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //if (getSp().getBoolean(Sp.SP_MORE_APP_UP, false)) {
        readJson();
        //}
        this.rv = findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(items, this, true);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setmClickListener(this);




        findViewById(R.id.top_bar_check).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.top_bar_menu).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.top_bar_back).setOnClickListener(this);

    }




 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
        loadForm();
       
        if (getSp().getBoolean(Sp.SP_IS_FAQ, true)) {
//            startActivity(new Intent(this, FaqActivity.class));
            getSp().edit().putBoolean(Sp.SP_IS_FAQ, false).commit();
        }
        if (getSp().getBoolean(Sp.SP_IS_FREE5DAY, false)) {
        }
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found solution? I'm struggling with with similar issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you call

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

before

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);`

I moved all Consent-Related code to a separate method `initializeConsent()` in the base class, and I called `initializeConsent()` as last method in my subclass's `onCreate()` method.

Additionally, I call

`MobileAds.initialize`

only in method `onConsentFormLoadSuccess`, it then looks like this:

```
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        DisplayNumberActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if(consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    DisplayNumberActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            //reset all DSGVO information for next trial
                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm(); //neuerlicher Aufruf, sollte nun ConsentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED haben. Dort wird dann initializeMobileAds() aufgerufen

                                        }
                                    });

                        } else if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED
                                || consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.NOT_REQUIRED) {
                            //Form muss nicht mehr angezeigt werden, Ads können geladen werden
                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                logInfo("DSGVO Consent obtained");
                            } else {
                                logInfo("DSGVO Consent not required");
                            }
                            //ads können jedenfalls geladen werden, Admob checkt ob es personalisierte werbung sein darf
                                    initializeMobileAds();


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(DisplayNumberActivity.this, "DSGVO Consent status: " + consentInformation.getConsentStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            logInfo("unexpected DSGVO Consent: "  + consentInformation.getConsentStatus());
                            initializeMobileAds();
                        }
                }
```